# C++ custom #pragma

Tags: c++, macros, pragma

I would like to know how to make the compiler understand a customized argument for `#pragma` macro.

My goal is to execute external script using macro, I suppose using `#pragma` is the way to go; if there are other ways to do so, please let me know.

Syntax would be something like:

```
#pragma add_controller(class_name, "class_alias")
```

so that I can generate a dynamic .h file containing the following:

`register_controller<class_name>("class_alias");`

and append to the end of file everytime the compiler interpret this `#pragma`.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want these things to do [what happens with these pragmas, when, where and how]? And what compiler is "my compiler" - are you looking to add this as extra options to some open source compiler by writing new code, or what do you plan to do?

Comment: Pragmas are decided upon by the compiler manufacturer.  Many of them are compiler specific.  Are you writing your own compiler?

Comment: You can do this if this is really your compiler (i.e. one you wrote). Some compilers offer APIs for writing extensions but I would not recommend to go this route. It would be much easier to generate your files with some other tool, e.g. a python script. You can have it scan your sources as a part of your build process.

Comment: thats the way I do now. I was trying to make it more transparent to the developer, but thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pragmas are builtin features of a compiler, and compiler-specific. You can't change or extend them in the general case, unless you're willing to tamper with the compiler itself.
Asking programmers to use a custom built compiler is probably not the best way to make your code more useable :).

For your example, you could use a macro:

```
#define add_controller(name, alias) register_controller<name>(alias)
```

and use it like so:

```
add_controller(whatever_controller, "whatever_alias");
```